# Mapping One symbol's Support/Resistance to another Symbol

Tags: futures, normalization

I wish to map and display the Support/Resistance lines (i.e. SMA20_daily) of ES onto NQ graph as I think they are mutually effecting each other, how may I achieve this? Do I need to do some kind of normalization?

For example, I have a SMA20_daily of ES, is there anyway I can 'map' this support/resistance line to the NQ chart, so that I can see the SMA20_daily_ES on my NQ chart, therefore plan an entry/exit of NQ? (i.e. If I believe when ES touches this line, it will reverse, than I can plan to do reversal strategy on NQ, as NQ is the symbol I wish to trade)

I have tried using simple ratio method, but it didn't produce the correct mapping. :(

Price of SMA20_daily_ES on NQ Chart = (Price_NQ/Price_ES)*(SMA20_daily_ES)

Any advices will be awesome.

Thank you guys!

Comment: which platform/programming language

Comment: Thinkorswim / Thinkscript

Comment: For a start support and resistance lines are a nonsense waste of time, get a proper quantitative finance education and save thousands if not millions of dollars wasted on chartistry nonsense.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe take the log ratio?

```
log( Price_ES / SMA_ES ) == log( Price_NQ / ES_equiv_SMA_NQ )
```

simplify and set

```
log( Price_ES / SMA_ES ) = X
```

where X is just a known constant, and then substitute and rearrange

```
ES_equiv_SMA_NQ = Price_NQ / e^X
```

Comment: Hmm just tried it, it produced the exact same result as the simple division ratio :(